# handling login/logout redirects

Tags: redirect, login, logout

I have a couple issues with the way Wordpress handles redirects on login and logout.

Standard behaviour is:

```
login: /wp-login.php (with no redirect_to url) -> /wp-admin.php 
logout: /wp-admin.php -> /wp-login.php
```

What want is:

```
login: /wp-login.php (with no redirect_to url) -> homepage
logout: /wp-admin.php -> homepage
```

Would prefer a coded solution please. It helps me to learn and understand how Wordpress works.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really does belong in a plugin, but you *can* just as easily drop it in your theme's `functions.php`

```
function default_login_redirect( $redirect, $request_redirect )
{
    if ( $request_redirect === '' )
        $redirect = home_url();
    return $redirect; 
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'default_login_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: No worries. It's going into a custom plugin. Thanks.

Comment: That worked. Those filters are hard to find sometimes :)